# How to set custom route name before main route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I want to add username before each route..

ex:

```
sam/productDashboard

james/productDashboard
```

note - Username is getting from session.

i tried like this. it doesn't work

> Route::get( session()->get('name').'/productDashboard',[ProductController::class,'ProductDashboard'])->name('productDashboard');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to use variable inside a route.
Do it like this:

```
Route::get('{username}/productDashboard',[ProductController::class,'ProductDashboard'])->name('productDashboard');
```

and when you are referencing to this route with a link do it this way:

```
<a href="{{route('productDashboard',['username' => session()->get('name')])}}">Link</>
```

Answer (score 0):

it registered on the start you can't do in this way

You could set it like params

```
Route::get('{username}/productDashboard',[ProductController::class,'ProductDashboard'])->name('productDashboard');
```